# Symbol for the shape of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I'm writing a technical document and need to describe some mathematics involving the shape of a matrix.  I realize that I can write $X_{m\times n}$ and someone can simply see the dimensions.  I'm wondering if there is some symbol for a function that, when applied, yields a result like the following?

$$\psi(X_{m\times n})=(m,n)$$

Comment: I don't think there is any such "well-established/well-known" function of this sort, but you can feel free to define it :).

Comment: How about $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$?

Comment: '$\mathrm{size}(\mathbf{A})$' has been used in the manner you mention, though it is by no means standard or well-established. Luckily with context it's fairly clear what it's meant to represent. (It *is* pretty standard in numerical computing, being the usual notation used in linear algebra libraries.)

Comment: I might also consider $\text{shape}(A)$, which is reminiscent of Numpy's `A.shape` syntax.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is common. More generally, when dealing with an $(r,s)$ tensor over $\mathbb{R}$ with covariant dimensions of $m_1,...,m_r$ and contravariant dimensions of $n_1,...,n_s$ I like the notation
$$^{r}_{s}\mathbb{R}^{m_1,...,m_r}_{n_1,...,n_s}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that your function acts over some space of the $X_{mn}$ matrices (matrices of dimension $m\times n$), and gives as a result a tuple of indices $(m,n)$, which are just the dimensions of the matrix (or any other integers $m,n$)? That is pretty much what one interprets from the equation you wrote. Something like:
\begin{eqnarray}
f:X_{mn}\to \mathbb{Z}^{2}|f(X_{mn})=(m,n)
\end{eqnarray}
The way to read it would be something like: the function $f$ that acting over the space of matrices $X$ of dimension $(m,n)$, gives as a result the pair of integers $(m,n)$. Usually, $f$ is just to declare a generic function acting over some domain; you can of course use any other symbol $\psi$ if you want to, as long as your symbol matches the definition above.

Comment: Wonderful!  Thanks.  I'm more a computer scientist than a mathematician, so I wasn't sure about how I might notate it.